# Oracle primary key seq_id not sort in order in select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I defined `seq_id` column as `NUMBER(10)`, when I select from this table, the record with `seq_id = 10` is after shown `1` - not after `9`.

How should I make the rows get sorted in numeric order? I know order by seq_id will make it numeric order. But I have seen other tables their counter & seq_id are default in numeric order.

[image: Below is the screenshot, 10 is behind 1 not 9]

Comment: Have you used `order by seq_id`?

Comment: Really looks to me like it's being treated like text and not a number  Are you sure you're not converting it somewhere or concatenating it to a string so an implicit type conversion is occurring?  Though.... you'd think it would be left aligned...

Comment: By default text is left-aligned, so the picture is quite strange if you have `order by seq_id` in your code

Comment: Please edit question and show the DLL

Comment: As Gordon hinted to: if you do not have an ORDER BY, don't expect any order. What you got maybe just luck or an artifact of the plan. As you said the fiend is number(10), and it is right-aligned in your output, this hints that there's no order by in your SELECT.

Comment: I guess @xqbert is right. I have another function to get the increment then insert into this table. It probably somehow convert it to string.

Comment: _"It probably somehow convert it to string."_  Well, you fail to show the query, you fail to show the DDL for the table, and you fail to show the suspected INSERT.  Youi've given us _nothing_ concrete to go on, so everything at this point is just a guess.  Please update you question to add the necessary information.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify an `order by` clause the order in which rows are returned is arbitrary.  If you care about the order of rows, you must use an `order by`.

For most tables in simple `select` statements without a `where` clause, rows will usually be returned in the way they are physically ordered on disk.  For small tables that never undergo deletes, never have updates that cause row migration, and never have multiple threads doing inserts, that physical order is likely to correspond to the numeric order of the sequence.  But that is not something that you should depend on.